# How can I add multiple IAM users to Systems Manager with diffent SSM? AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm, aws-session-manager

I want to log into a IAM user through AWS and my EC2 through systems manager. Then I want to log into different IAM user and access same EC2 except with a different SSM so home dir isn't the same and they don't have access to each others files. How can I do this?

I am able to log into systems manager from different IAM accounts but it still uses the same SSM.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean "different SSM"??? there is only one AWS Systems manager. Based on your tag, I think you mean System Manager Session Manager...

In Session Manager you are interacting with `ssm-user` account that is created for you by AWS. So, it really doesn't matter which IAM account you are using - on the box itself it's the same account